# Are there any open source projects to implement efficient and reliable TCP server

Tags: http, tcp, messaging

Is there any open source projects to implement efficient and reliable `TCP` server ? 
what I want to do is to create android messaging service based on `TCP` communication, and the server-side is what I matter here

### edit

`Java` is my preferred language

Comment: What's your preferred programming language? That would help narrow down the wide range of choices just a bit...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Netty, Apache Mina, Grizzly immediately come to mind. Erlang/OTP is also an excellent choice.